# Map and forEach functions overriding other values with last element. How can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, foreach

```js
let loopMatchObj =  { $match: {  } };
let loopProjectObj = { $project: { } };
let loopGroupObj = { $group: { } };

let facetObj = {}

let paramList =  ["activeEnergy","activePower"];
let aggregationType = ["min","max","avg","sum"];

paramList.map((item) => {
    
    loopProjectObj['$project'][item] = 1;
    
    aggregationType.map((type) => {
        loopGroupObj['$group'][type] = {};
        loopGroupObj['$group'][type]['$' + type] = "$" + item;
    })
    
    facetObj[item] = [ loopMatchObj, loopProjectObj, loopGroupObj]
})

console.log(facetObj.activeEnergy[2])
```

I am writing above code to write some mongoDB query dynamically in code. But the problem I am facing is it is overriding the all the values in group object with last value only (activePower). When I console log group object in activeEnergy array I am getting below result

```
           {
            $group: {
            minValue: { $min: "$activePower" },
            maxValue: { $max: "$activePower" },
            avgValue: { $avg: "$activePower" },
            sumValue: { $sum: "$activePower" },
            }
```

Expected output

```
           {
            $group: {
            minValue: { $min: "$activeEnergy" },
            maxValue: { $max: "$activeEnergy" },
            avgValue: { $avg: "$activeEnergy" },
            sumValue: { $sum: "$activeEnergy" },
            }
```

Note: This question is about Javascript only nothing related to mongoDB queries.

Comment: because you are using the same object over and over. Move the declarations inside the map. And your map should be forEach.

Comment: Move the top 3 `let` declarations inside the first `.map`